# Odoo sales reports pipeline filter by res partner category

Tags: python, pivot, report, odoo, odoo-10

In `Sales -> Reports -> Pipeline` I would like to allow to filter by res.partner.category.

In Odoo `res.partner` has a field [category_id](https://github.com/spookiecookie/odoo/blob/ab60d773eb84a527b3167d7efaf169f70c5c9786/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L167)

```
category_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner.category', column1='partner_id',
                                column2='category_id', string='Tags', default=_default_category)
```

I tried copying

```
category_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner.category', column1='partner_id',
                                column2='category_id', string='Tags', default=_default_category)` to my crm_opportunity_report (that has inherited crm.opportunity.report) but I get errors.
```

Tried adding field

```
category_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.partner.category', relation="res_partner_res_partner_category_rel",
                                column1='category_id', column2='partner_id')
```

and this failed too.

**How to add category name as a filter to crm_opportunity_report? What can be done to allow filtering by category?**

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to use many-to-many relations in pivot. You can't group by such relations.

Comment: @CZoellner Thank You, maybe I could somehow join Tag names into a string "'Tagname 1', 'Tagname 2', 'Tagname 3' for each row in crm_opportunity_report?

Comment: Yes, that should work

Comment: Thank you I am developing the solution and so far have this query  `SELECT rp.id, array_agg(rpc.name ORDER BY rp.id, rpc.name)  
  FROM res_partner_res_partner_category_rel rpcl 
  JOIN res_partner_category rpc ON rpc.id = rpcl.category_id
  JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = rpcl.partner_id  
  GROUP BY rp.id
  ORDER BY rp.id`

Comment: @CZoellner anyway Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's somewhat solution (based on discussion: see comments on the question). It makes a string ("'Tagname1';'Tagname2';'Tagname3';...") from tag names to filter on.

```
             SELECT                        
                        c.id,
                        c.name as name,
                        c.date_deadline,

                        c.date_open as opening_date,
                        c.date_closed as date_closed,
                        c.date_last_stage_update as date_last_stage_update,

                        c.user_id,
                        c.probability,
                        c.stage_id,
                        stage.name as stage_name,
                        c.type,
                        c.company_id,
                        c.priority,
                        c.team_id,
                        (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM mail_message m
                         WHERE m.model = 'crm.lead' and m.res_id = c.id) as nbr_activities,
                        c.active,
                        c.campaign_id,
                        c.source_id,
                        c.medium_id,
                        c.partner_id,
                        c.city,
                        c.country_id,
                        c.planned_revenue as total_revenue,
                        c.planned_revenue*(c.probability/100) as expected_revenue,
                        c.create_date as create_date,
                        extract('epoch' from (c.date_closed-c.create_date))/(3600*24) as  delay_close,
                        abs(extract('epoch' from (c.date_deadline - c.date_closed))/(3600*24)) as  delay_expected,
                        extract('epoch' from (c.date_open-c.create_date))/(3600*24) as  delay_open,
                        c.lost_reason,
                        c.date_conversion as date_conversion,

                        COALESCE(rp.customer, FALSE) as is_customer,
                        COALESCE(x.Categories, '') AS Categories

                    FROM
                        "crm_lead" c

                    LEFT JOIN "res_partner" rp ON rp.id = c.partner_id
                    LEFT JOIN "crm_stage" stage ON stage.id = c.stage_id
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (
SELECT rp.id AS partner_id, array_to_string(array_agg(''''||rpc.name||'''' ORDER BY rp.id, rpc.name),';') AS Categories
  FROM res_partner_res_partner_category_rel rpcl 
  JOIN res_partner_category rpc ON rpc.id = rpcl.category_id
  JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = rpcl.partner_id  
  GROUP BY rp.id
  ORDER BY rp.id

  ) AS x ON x.partner_id = c.partner_id

                    GROUP BY c.id, stage.name, COALESCE(rp.customer, FALSE), COALESCE(x.Categories, '')
                    ORDER BY c.partner_id
```